# Can deep learning TensorFlow models be trained in Python, pickled and used for prediction in C++?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, serialization, pickle

I have learnt a neural net based model using TensorFlow in Python.

> I would like to store this model in a file and be able to load it into
>   memory in a C++ program for prediction later.

I am doing a comparative study of my machine learning model versus a standard algorithm written in C++. For this reason, I would like to load the model and do the prediction in C++ since I don't want the internals of the programming language to cause differences in the runtimes of the implementations.

> Are there other ways to keep the comparisons language-neutral?

Comment: this link may be of some help https://medium.com/@hamedmp/exporting-trained-tensorflow-models-to-c-the-right-way-cf24b609d183

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I think you can do it using bazel (google's tool for TF). Once you make sure that you are saving checkpoints, build the project. It would create executable file for you to use in c++.